# Uploading files to Google Cloud Storage with Flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload some images to GCS via an App Engine instance using Flask, but every time the file it's uploaded, when I download it I get a corrupt file. What am I doing wrong ?

I've downloaded and used the Google Cloud Storage client the way is in the docs.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        extension = secure_filename(file.filename).rsplit('.', 1)[1]
        options = {}
        options['retry_params'] = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
        options['content_type'] = 'image/' + extension
        bucket_name = "gcs-tester-app"
        path = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + str(secure_filename(file.filename))
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            try:
                with gcs.open(path, 'w', **options) as f:
                    f.write(str(file))
                    print jsonify({"success": True})
                return jsonify({"success": True})
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(e)
                return jsonify({"success": False})
```

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're uploading (writing to the gcs stream) the str representation of the file object, not the file contents.

try this:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        extension = secure_filename(file.filename).rsplit('.', 1)[1]
        options = {}
        options['retry_params'] = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
        options['content_type'] = 'image/' + extension
        bucket_name = "gcs-tester-app"
        path = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + str(secure_filename(file.filename))
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            try:
                with gcs.open(path, 'w', **options) as f:
                    f.write(file.stream.read())# instead of f.write(str(file))
                    print jsonify({"success": True})
                return jsonify({"success": True})
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(e)
                return jsonify({"success": False})
```

But this is not the most efficient way to do this, also, there is a 32mb cap on file uploads straight from app engine, the way to avoid this is by signing an upload url with GCS and upload the file directly from the front-end to GCS, or you can create a file upload url with blobstore and a handler to do the post-upload processing, as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Comment: Okay! So if I understand it well, it's better to create a file upload url because if not I'm uploading the file to App Engine and then writing it in Clou Storage ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Merqurio the idea is to have the file uploaded through google service and you only handle a small portion of the load, also, if you're running this on app engine, there is a cap of 32mb on file uploads, bigger files would have to go straight to blobstorage or gcs.